# Attach Debugger to multiple processes via powershell

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, powershell, visual-studio-2013, powershell-4.0

I have several processes running that I'd like to attach to the VS debugger via powershell.

Currently, I can do this: `Get-Process NServiceBus.Host | Debug-Process`

If there is only one process, then I am prompted to select the correct debugger and I can continue.

However, if there are more than one processes, when I'm prompted to select a debugger for the second process, I am unable to select the currently running instance of Visual Studio.

How can I use powershell to attach multiple processes to a running instance of visual studio for debuggin?

Comment: I have never known or attempted to attach more than one process to VS debugger.  I simply don't think it can be done.

Comment: @JohnPeters I do several times a day through the VIsual Studio Debug > Attach to Process.

Comment: Wow!  VS allows multiple process debugging at one time?

Comment: @JohnPeters Yup. One way is if you use 'Multiple Startup Projects' at the solution level and start debugging (F5), then you are debugging multiple processes.

Answer (score 6):

To get hold of the active visual studio instance ...

**$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE")**

... and to make it attach to a set of processes ...

**($dte.debugger.localprocesses | Where Name -Match "proc(one|two).exe").Attach()**

... it seems that a delay might be necessary between each attach if it takes too long otherwise visual studio is busy and rejects the call.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but somehow it is not working properly. I get this error: + ($dte.debugger.localprocesses | Where <<<<  Name -Match "proc(one|two).exe").Attach()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: That second line needs to be something like this ... I imagine I only had one process found at the time I ran it ... suspect not zero or many processes might cause the error you saw etalon11.

$dte.debugger.localprocesses | Where Name -Match "proc(one|two).exe" | % { $_.Attach() }

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, softwarebear. I was not able to get your exact command line working, but after adding curly brackets and running at an Administrator Powershell prompt, this command line successfully attached the debugger to all the running w3wp.exe processes:

```
$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('VisualStudio.DTE')
$dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses | Where {$_.Name -like '*w3wp.exe'} | %{$_.Attach()}
```

Ideally this could be executed from within Visual Studio with a keystroke, but Visual Studio doesn't support Powershell without an add-in, and the Macro editor was removed after VS2010. Following [this advice](https://nickmeldrum.com/blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010) I tried adding this ScriptBlock as an 'External Tool' in a powershell.exe command line, but it didn't attach the debugger and produced no output.

Comment: GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0") for Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Must be run in a Powershell version below 7,. PS7 is based on .NET Core and has no System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal

Comment: GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE") for Visual Studio 2022